# Range of divisors (Java)

Tags: java

I'm not quite sure what I'm having trouble with here and I'm hoping someone can help me. This is my first post on Stack Overflow, and I'm relatively new to programming, so I hope I don't offend anyone's sensibilities around here.

Here's the prompt (yes, it's a Project Euler question and please don't give the answer away): What is the lowest number which is divisible by every number between 1 and 20?

Here's what I coded:

```
    int target = 21;
    int divisor;
    boolean success = false;
    while (!success)
    {
        for (divisor = 1; divisor < 21; divisor++)
        {
            if (target % divisor != 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (divisor == 20)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        target++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(target);
```

The answer I'm getting (232792581) is being flagged as incorrect by P.E. Can anyone tell me what I'm getting wrong here?

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Well, that number is obviously not divisible by two. Maybe reduce your problem to something you can do by hand (like the first number divisible by everything up to 5) and see where your algorithm has gone wrong.

Comment: Hint: you do something even after you've found the correct answer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `if (divisor == 20) {success = true;             }` block?

Comment: No, I noticed that the answer was clearly wrong, but my question is more in the process part of the problem. Where is my process am I breaking down?

EDIT: No, I see where you're saying that I'm doing something wrong after "success" (there is still one being added to the answer), but the given answer minus one isn't correct either. I'll correct that error, but it doesn't help me...

Comment: @PM 77-1: I was trying to achieve the appropriate loop break so that the program would render a right answer. I still needed to add another (if success) {break;} to break the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have `target++` in the wrong place. The way your code is now, this is being called inside the `for` loop where you test the numbers - i.e. you change the target while checking things against it. Move the `target++` statement so that it is out of the `for` loop but still in the `while` loop.

Comment: Here's what I've got with those changes, plus the changes mentioned above:

int target = 21;
int divisor;
boolean success = false;
while (!success)
{
 target++;
 for (divisor = 1; divisor < 21; divisor++)
 {
  //System.out.println(target);
  if (target % divisor != 0)
  {
   break;
  }
  else
  {
   if (divisor == 20)
   {
    success = true;
   }
  }
 }
 
}

System.out.println(target);

This still does not render a correct answer. It seems (and I'm in the 10's of billions as of this edit) that this results in no answer. Anything else?

Comment: I compiled and ran that exact same code and it worked just fine.

Comment: I don't know. I would assume so.